# Question about a specific functor in Lie superalgebras

Tags: lie-superalgebras

Given any superassociative algebra, a Lie superalgebra with a Lie superbracket $[a,b]=ab- (-1)^{|a||b|} ba$ is constructed and satisfies

- $[a,b]=-(-1)^{|a||b|}[b,a]$
- $[a,[b,c]] = [[a,b],c] + (−1)^{|a||b}[b,[a,c]].$

Let we have a parity reversion functor which changes the parity of the components of superspace. We consider the odd Lie bracket of parity $\epsilon$ such that $|[a,b]|=|a|+|b|+ \epsilon $ (mod 2), then how can it be shown that the odd case is reduced to the even?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. The parity reversion functor isn't monoidal, so it doesn't send superalgebras to superalgebras or Lie superalgebras to Lie superalgebras.